# Why do people fork and then don't change anything?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm a new user of GitHub (https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin) and don't understand one thing.

Why do people fork repo and then don't do any change to that repo ?

For example :

- https://github.com/JakeWharton/StickyListHeaders
- https://github.com/donnfelker/node-native-zip
- https://github.com/kevinsawicki/flurfunk-camelbot
- https://github.com/gorillamania/htmlParser
- https://github.com/shama/faster-than-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may do it as insurance against the repository being removed.  They may also intend to make changes, but never actually do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I suspect the real reason is that it is much easier to fork something (literally one-click) than to remove it afterwards (and many cannot be bothered to remove the repositories which they forked by accident).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason is that the person doing the clone wants to freeze the repository as it is at the time of their clone, kind of their own tag.